# Can ITfoxtec SAML2 supprot multiple IdPs?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, saml-2.0, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I am attempting to make my ASP.NET MVC web app provide SSO to multiple IdPs, and I am wondering if it is possible to support this scenario using the ITfoxtec.SAML2 library.

I have many different clients, several of whom want to have an SSO integration with my service. Each of the clients has a different sub-domain (e.g. business1.myapp.com, business2.myapp.com, etc.) and I will need to use their unique part of the name to look up their metadata and produce a configuration that will talk back to them.

The example code that I have seen seems to be supporting a more traditional one IdP to one SP scenario.

Additionally, if any one knows of a non-Core ASP.NET MVC example application, I would be profoundly grateful to know where to find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case I would implement some `Saml2Configuration` logic, where I can ask for a specific `Saml2Configuration` for the current IdP. This specific `Saml2Configuration` is then used in the `AuthController`.

After a `binding.ReadSamlResponse(Request.ToGenericHttpRequest(), saml2AuthnResponse)` with a generic `Saml2Configuration` you can read the IdP issuer in `saml2AuthnResponse.Issuer`. And then load the correct `Saml2Configuration`.

A link to a non-Core ASP.NET MVC relaying party sample application https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/tree/master/test/TestWebApp

--

An **alternative solution** is to add a security broker like https://www.foxids.com in between your app and the IdPs. Then the security broker handles meltable IdPs and your application only need to trust the security broker as one IdP (using SAML 2.0 or OpenID Connect). FoxIDs is also open source and free.

Comment: I have the same issue, can you provide some sample for it?

Comment: I have some Saml2Configuration logic code in FoxIDs you can look at https://github.com/ITfoxtec/FoxIDs/blob/master/src/FoxIDs/Logic/Saml/SamlConfigurationLogic.cs