# implement multiple company login from azure(itfoxtec)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I have to implement multiple company login from azure so How to do this? Right now I am successfully implemented a single company sign on with ITfoxtec.Identity.SAML2 but Now I have to do multiple companies so Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

If you used OpenID Connect it would be possible to create an Azure AD multitenant enterprise application and check which tenant the user came from after login.

But because it is SAML 2.0 you need to create multiple Azure AD single tenant enterprise applications, one in each tenant. In this case you need to trust multiple IdPs, please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59761654/can-itfoxtec-saml2-supprot-multiple-idps) on how to trust multiple IdPs.

Comment: Hello,
I understand but what configuration changes I will do for this multitenant enterprise application?

Comment: Answered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66595064/how-i-setup-flow-of-multiple-tenant-in-azure-ad-asp-net-core-itfoxtec/66597079#66597079